# Run BackgroundService with parameter from code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr, .net-5

How I can run `BackgroundService` by parameter from code?

I have `SignalR`, user join to group (example `group:a, group:b, group:c, group:d`). I want run `CatService` with current join group:

```
public class CatHub : Hub
{
    public async Task JoinToGroup(string group)
    {
        // how i can run new CatService with current group ??? 
        CORE_RUN_NEW_SERVICE<CatService>(_, group);
    }
}

public class CatService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IHubContext<CatHub> _hub;
    private readonly string _group;  
    public CandleSig(IHubContext<CatHub> hub, string group)
    {
        _hub = hub;
        _group = group
    }

    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _hub.SendToGroup(_group, "test")
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), ct);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can fetch all implementations of IHostedService from IServiceCollection, find the right BackgroundService, and run it. When it comes to passing parameters, pass it through DI (injecting into ctor)

Comment: That does not fulfill the requirements. He want's to create *a new service* from the Hub Method foreach group. As @Florian already mentioned modifiying the SerivceCollection is not possible. So from my point of view that won't work...

Comment: @FloriUni how we can resolve problem? create static task collection ?

Comment: @padavan Do you wan't the interval of 1 minute per group or overall for all serivce? In other words: One timer per group or one for all groups?

Comment: timer for example, there will be unlimited wait task handler:   await statistic.newSignal(x => _hub.SendToGroup(_group, x,message) )

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify the number of background services once the application is running.

However, you can create a *single* background service that has a queue. First define the queue:

```
public sealed class MyBackgroundQueue
{
  private readonly Channel<string> _channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>();

  public ValueTask QueueAsync(string item) => _channel.WriteAsync(item);

  public IAsyncEnumerable<T> DequeueAllAsync(CancellationToken ct) =>
      _channel.ReadAllAsync(ct);
}
```

inject it into your background service:

```
public class CatService : BackgroundService
{
  private readonly IHubContext<CatHub> _hub;
  private readonly MyBackgroundQueue _queue;
  public CatService(IHubContext<CatHub> hub, MyBackgroundQueue queue)
  {
    _hub = hub;
    _queue = queue;
  }

  protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken ct)
  {
    await foreach (var item in _queue.DequeueAllAsync(ct);
      _hub.SendToGroup(_group, "test")
  }
}
```

and also into your hub:

```
public class CatHub : Hub
{
  private readonly MyBackgroundQueue _queue;
  public CatHub(MyBackgroundQueue queue) => _queue = queue;

  public async Task JoinToGroup(string group)
  {
    await _queue.EnqueueAsync(group);
  }
}
```

Comment: if channel count changed how will CatService  know about it ?

Comment: @padavan: The `await foreach` loop will get another item.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, modifiying the service collection after starting the application is not supported, so starting a further `BackgroundService` isn't possible.

Comment: what i should do ? Create static locale ConcurrentDictionary and add new TASK ?

Comment: I would register the service in the startup.cs, inject the service to the hub and pass the information from the hub to the service using a separate method so the actual group gets "registered". The worker method of the backgroundService should iterate over the groups afterwards...

Comment: Need example , dont understand .